# How to replace the currently selected text in Applescript? How does Devontechnologies WordServices' do it?

Tags: applescript, services

Devontechnologies offers a collection of services that let's the user perform some common tasks on text (upper case, lower case, ROT13 and so on). They do it without (as far as I can tell at least) using the clipboard (pbpaste/pbcopy).

I have googled a lot about this but the only solutions I have found are based on pbcopy/pbpaste and I want to avoid that. Any suggestions?

I am creating my own service similar to Devon's WordServices that takes an editable piece of text, manipulates it and finally replaces the original text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an Automator contextual workflow service.

1. Open Automator select `Contextual Workflow`
   [image]
2. Enter the following settings

   - Workflow Receives: text
   - In: Any Applicaition
   - Check Output replaces selected text
3. Add the AppleScript Action

[image]

4. The selected text will be in the `input` variable. It will return the `input` variable at the end thus replacing the original text with the new text

**The workflow can be accessed by selecting text, right clicking, and going to Services.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking around in Automator but at the wrong spot. Just curious, I thought everything in Automator could be done using Applescript, am I mistaken?

Comment: @d-b Most things not this.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have something called "Contextual Workflow" but I do have something called "Service" with the same icon. Which version are you using?

Comment: @d-b That’s the correct one. See pictures.